# ReviewBoard 3.0.11 cannot set up SVN repository

Tags: svn, review-board

I have a custom SVN repo I want to review, so I installed ReviewBoard on my server, but I cannot set up any repository type other than TeamFoundation Server.

I installed python-svn and other packages using this [article](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-review-board-on-ubuntu-16-10), but I have no "SVN" option.[image]

I can provide any additional data if it helps

Even when I choose Bitbucket, I have no Git/Mercurial options
[image]